# text-align breaking jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to writ an overlay for a few of my divs to prevent users from going to far without doing previous tasks. I have the overlay working and the message displaying, but when I try and center the message thats when the problem arrises.

my jQuery looks like this

```
$("<div>You have to complete your previous tasks before you can move on.</div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
}).appendTo($(".disabled-box").css("position", "relative"));
```

and as soon as I put

```
   text-align: "center"
```

in there it breaks and throws the error message

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: use camel case: `textAlign: "center",` or wrap text-align key inside quotes

Comment: It is not a duplicate because the text-align they were using there was not working here.

Comment: It is a duplicate. There are a lot of answers with a lot of possible ways to do it. I'm sure they work. If you're looking for a different answer (whatever...), opening a bounty on the existing question is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to this:

```
$("<div>You have to complete your previous tasks before you can move on.</div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)",
    textAlign: 'center'
}).appendTo($(".disabled-box").css("position", "relative"));
```

For styles, the dash is always replaced with [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) when referring to styles using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew there was something like that going on, but couldn't pin point it!

Answer (score 0):

Add it like this:

```
$("<div>You have to complete your previous tasks before you can move on.</div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    top: 0,
    "text-align": "center",
    left: 0,
    background: "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
}).appendTo($(".disabled-box").css("position", "relative"));
```

Comment: I tried that, it then says there is an illegal string or center.

Comment: I just made an edit because I forgot a comma, did you try it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
textAlign: "center"
```

but

```
"text-align": "center"
```

would also work. It's up to you.

I just like to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: "fixed"` and styling `margins` I do it all the time showing my own messages. I think your dialog will be static on your screen.

---

Don't waste code doing it on JQuery, I'ts better doing a class center for your div.

```
.center{margin:0 0;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;position:fixed;background-color:#FAFAFA;overflow:hidden;opacity:0.9;z-index:99;}
```

---

Hope it helps.